# Is it possible to add a value to a hidden text box field in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Recently, I came across a web page where someone asked how to add some value to a hidden field. 
Since I am new to JQuery, I tried using Javascript instead and came up with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function t() {
document.testform.testfield.value = "helloworld";
}
-->
</script>
</HEAD>
<body onLoad="t()">
<form name="testform" id="testform">
<input type="hidden" name="testfield" id="testfield">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works only in non-hidden Text Box field.
I am not sure if JQuery can do it.
Is it possible to add a value to a hidden text box field in JQuery?

Please help if you could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**yes ;)**

```
$("input[name=testfield]").attr("value","helloworld");
```

or

```
$("#testfield").attr("value","helloworld");
```

or

```
$("#testfield").val("helloworld"); //Thx Felix Klinger
```

**and if you wan't to show the form:**

```
$("input[name=testfield]").attr("type","text");
```

or

```
$("#testfield").attr("type","text");
```

Comment: Or just `$("#testfield").val("helloworld");` Btw., `testform` is wrong, should be `testfield` and I don't think that you can make a input field of type `hidden` visible with `show`.

Comment: @Felix Kling - Thanks ;) i need to sleep a little ahaha